# How to embed additional strings into prompt with PromptTemplate?

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I would like to use `PromptTemplate` and `ConversationChain` to embed what I have previously saved in the prompt.

```
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(human_prefix="ユーザー", memory_key="chat_history")
prompt = PromptTemplate(
  input_variables=["chat_history", "related_info", "input"],
  template="""下記はユーザーとAIの友好的な会話です。AIはお喋りで、文脈から具体的で詳細なことをたくさん教えてくれます。AIは質問に対する答えを知らない時、知らないと答えます。
関連する情報：
{related_info}

現在の会話：
{chat_history}
ユーザー：{input}
AI："""
)
chain = ConversationChain(
  llm=llm,
  verbose=True,
  memory=memory,
  prompt=prompt
)
```

```
db = Chroma(
  embedding_function=OpenAIEmbeddings(),
  persist_directory="./database"
)
related_info = ""
for i in db.similarity_search(message, top_k=2):
  related_info = related_info + "\n" + i.page_content

result = chain.predict(related_info=related_info, input=message)
```

In these code, I want to embed `related_info` into prompt, but not worked.

What should I do?